# Page reloading even when I put e.preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to send a post request and every time I post by clicking the on page button, it reloads the page even with the e.preventDefault(). Can anyone see why this would happen

```
const model = document.getElementById('model')
const pressure = document.getElementById('pressure')
const flowrate = document.getElementById('flowrate')
const turndown = document.getElementById('turndown')
const button = document.getElementById('btn')
const search = document.getElementById('search')
const resultHeading = document.getElementById('result-heading')
const single_mealEl = document.getElementById('single-meal')
const mealsEl = document.getElementById('meals')
const image = document.getElementById('image')


button.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    alert('hello')
    let imageFile = image.files[0]
    
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image1', imageFile)
    formData.append('model', model.value)
    formData.append('image', image.files[0].name)
    

    axios.post('http://localhost:5500/api/v1', formData, {headers: {'Content-Type': 
    'multipart/form-data'}}).then(response => console.log(response.data))
    // await fetch(`http://localhost:5500/api/v1`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => 
    {mealsEl.innerHTML = data})
    })
```

Comment: Show us the HTML of that `<button>` and any ancestor `<form>` element.

Comment: BTW, `formData.append('image', image.files[0].name)`  <-- This is redundant as `formData.append('image1', imageFile)` will include the filename in its multipart header.

Comment: I would assume you need to prevent form submission and not click on button

Comment: @Justinas Always the better idea. Removes all doubt of what is supposed to happen

Comment: This is the HTML button I am using: <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn">Add Pump</button>

Comment: Justinas, I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If you have button type="button", then that button cannot submit the page without other script and you do NOT need the preventDefault. You likely have ANOTHER event listener, like document.onclick or something that reloads the page

Comment: Yeah, I thought this too but this is all I have in my js code.

Comment: If I remove the axios.post request it doesn't happen if that helps.

Comment: my backend controller looks like this and it seems to be the bottom line that is causing the page to reload. I'm using express-fileupload package.

 const createPump = async (req,res) => {
    const pump = await Pump.create(req.body)
    res.status(201).json({pump})
    console.log(req.body)
    let productImage = req.files.image1
    const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, '../public/uploads/' + `${productImage.name}`);
    await productImage.mv(imagePath);
}